# Android request response time difference between remote host vs localhost

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache

I have problem and can't figure it out.. I'm developing android app (posting, getting and parsing Json) and testing on localhost and remote host.. Everything works well but this. I'm using Xampp Apache/Php/MySQL on localhost.

I'm adding two different videos:

1. Remote test : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cl02F17n0y8
2. Local test : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Pb7RSv2UVk

As you can see, If i'm click faster buttons when app working on remote host, everything's working well.. But If click faster when on local host, there is a weird delay. I checked firewall, antivirus, httpd.conf, php.ini..

Application works fast with all functions both of remote and localhost except only this.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: are you using any remote apis?

Comment: and if you doubt its happening cz of any firewall or something then if you are havin linux machine...run this in terminal 
iptables -L

Comment: @NitishAgarwal Remote host is CENTOS 6.6 with Apache, I'm not using any remote apis.. I disabled firewall and antivirus, still same here.. No i haven't linux machine, working on windows. I think something blocking fast requests but i don't know what it is..